# How WooCommerce Coupons are stored in Database?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I need to run a script to check my coupons every time I have a new register, but I can't find where the coupons from coupon generator (WooCommerce) are stored.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> WooCommerce Coupon are stored in `wp_posts` table with `post_type => 'shop_coupon'`. And all the associated data are stored in `wp_postmeta` table.

You can use this MySQL query to get all the Coupon:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_coupon' ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

And this gets all coupons

```
SELECT p.`ID`, 
       p.`post_title`   AS coupon_code, 
       p.`post_excerpt` AS coupon_description, 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,          -- Discount type 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,          -- Coupon amount 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'free_shipping'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,          -- Allow free shipping 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'date_expires'        AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS date_expires,                -- Coupon expiry date 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'minimum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS minimum_amount,         -- Minimum spend 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'maximum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS maximum_amount,         -- Maximum spend 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'individual_use'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS individual_use,         -- Individual use only 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_sale_items' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_sale_items,         -- Exclude sale items 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_ids'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,                -- Products 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_ids'AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_ids,        -- Exclude products 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,             -- Product categories 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_categories,-- Exclude Product categories 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,         -- Email restrictions 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,                -- Usage limit per coupon 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit_per_user'   AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit_per_user,   -- Usage limit per user 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_count'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS total_used                  -- Usage count 
FROM   `wp_posts` AS p 
       INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` 
WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'shop_coupon' 
       AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' 
GROUP  BY p.`ID` 
ORDER  BY p.`ID` ASC;
```

Reference: [MySQL Query to Get All Coupon](https://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/mysql-query-to-get-all-coupon/)

Comment: Any idea where the expiry date might be?

Comment: @DeepakShenoy: expiry date is stored in `wp_postmeta` table against the `post_id` and `meta_key = expiry_date`. Please check the reference link attached with the answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for duplicate comment, left one on your website. Is it possible to retrieve order meta of the user that used the coupon? My coupon usage limit is set to 1, for all coupons. I would like ti include in the report the user's name, email address and possibly some other custom fields.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi @user1664798: As this question is not directly related with your question so I cannot update my answer, it would be grt if you can post a new question and ping me the link I'll try to figure out a solution, in a mean time you can check [this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42771538/5019802).

Comment: @RaunakGupta I have posted my question here. Hope this is how I am suppose to ping you? Thank you very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763254/adding-checkout-fields-data-to-the-coupon-export-of-woocommerce

Comment: @RaunakGupta I want to select all coupon that is publised 20 days ago and want to delete them. How do I select publish date as a range or how can I achieve it ?