# List Coupon with order details in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I have a site with 1000 coupons. All the coupons have a usage limit of one. Im using the code provided by Raunuk Gupta to export coupons directly from the SQL database.

[How WooCommerce Coupons are stored in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997287/5019802) ?

Is it possible to retrieve order meta of the user that used the coupon? I would like to include in the report the user's name, email address and possibly some other custom fields.

Thank you.

- We generate 1000 coupons and provide it to a company ( client ).
- Each coupon has a usage limit of 1.
- The company then distribute the coupons among their members.
- At the end of the month, we need to send a report to the company telling them:

  1. How many of the 1000 coupons were used. ( this can be done with the code provided at the link above )
  2. Then from the used coupons, we need to tell them who used it, in other words the name and email address of the user that placed the order.

[LINK TO SAMPLE EXCEL EXPORT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z26pogcordk077/sample-stack.xlsx?dl=0)
-The Yellow fields are from the COUPONS
-The Blue fields are from the ORDER

Comment: FIELDS REQUIRED: ID | coupon_code | coupon_description | discount_type | coupon_amount | product_ids | product_categories | usage_limit | total_usaged | order_id | billing_email | billing_first_name | billing_last_name | order_total

Answer (score 9):

Below MySQL query will list all your coupon associated with Order.

```
SELECT pc.post_title AS coupon_name,
       pc.post_excerpt AS coupon_description,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_ids'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_limit'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_count'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged,
       po.ID AS order_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_email'      AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'  AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_order_total'        AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS order_total
FROM `wp_posts` AS pc
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmc ON  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS woi ON pc.post_title = woi.order_item_name
    AND woi.order_item_type = 'coupon'
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS po ON woi.order_id = po.ID
    AND po.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND po.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-refunded') -- Added needed order status over here.
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmo ON po.ID = pmo.post_id
WHERE pc.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
GROUP BY po.ID
ORDER BY pc.ID DESC,
         po.ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 10 -- modify it accordingly.
```

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: Thank you! This works to export coupons with the associated order info. However, I was hoping to get an export as the initial Coupon export code you provided, but just with the added column of the order detail, should there be any.

Comment: I want to end up with the list exactly as before, but should the last field of "total_usaged" be 1, then i would like to see the name and email of the person that used that coupon. If the field "total_usaged" is NULL or 0, then the additional columns of name email will be empty. Is that possible? Than you

Comment: @user1664798: I didn't get you, can you please update your question with an example and also list the column that you want in the export.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question, added a sample excel file and also added the columns headings as a separate comment. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1664798: I have updated my answer. Please check this would fetch the desired result.

Comment: This works but I need to ad even more detail like the oder date and order status. Could you please point me in the right direction? i have managed to add the paid_date.

Comment: And also the selected payment method.

Comment: @user1664798: `posts.post_date` is the order date, `posts.post_status` is the order date. If the answer was helpful then do not forget to [upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400). :)