# Woocommerce: Get the total order value for each coupon use (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the answer from the following question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52852428/609630

```
SELECT pc.post_title AS coupon_name,
       pc.post_excerpt AS coupon_description,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_ids'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_limit'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_count'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged,
       po.ID AS order_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_email'      AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'  AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_order_total'        AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS order_total
FROM `wp_posts` AS pc
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmc ON  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS woi ON pc.post_title = woi.order_item_name
    AND woi.order_item_type = 'coupon'
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS po ON woi.order_id = po.ID
    AND po.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND po.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-refunded') -- Added needed order status over here.
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmo ON po.ID = pmo.post_id
WHERE pc.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
GROUP BY po.ID
ORDER BY pc.ID DESC,
         po.ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 10 -- modify it accordingly.
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'totm.pc.post_title' which is not functionally
>   dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by
>
> Error code 1055.

How can I correct it? The answer is marked as correct but I'm getting the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the non-aggregated columns present in select list, must come in GROUP BY clause. You are getting this error coz you are using some non-aggregated columns in select list but not using them in group by clause. Try below query -

```
SELECT pc.post_title AS coupon_name,
       pc.post_excerpt AS coupon_description,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_ids'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_limit'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,
       Max(CASE WHEN pmc.meta_key = 'usage_count'        AND  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id` THEN pmc.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged,
       po.ID AS order_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_email'      AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'  AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS billing_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN pmo.meta_key = '_order_total'        AND po.ID = pmo.post_id THEN pmo.meta_value END) AS order_total
FROM `wp_posts` AS pc
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmc ON  pc.`ID` = pmc.`post_id`
INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_order_items` AS woi ON pc.post_title = woi.order_item_name
    AND woi.order_item_type = 'coupon'
INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS po ON woi.order_id = po.ID
    AND po.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND po.post_status IN ('wc-completed', 'wc-processing', 'wc-refunded') -- Added needed order status over here.
INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pmo ON po.ID = pmo.post_id
WHERE pc.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
GROUP BY pc.post_title,
         pc.post_excerpt,
         po.ID
ORDER BY po.ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error when using your code

Comment: Are you sure you are using this query. This error should not be there as all the non-aggregated columns are now in group by clause.

Comment: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'totm.pc.ID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: There is no pc.ID in select clause, hence the issue. I have removed that now. Please try edited answer.