# Delete coupons stored in database WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I found this post: [How WooCommerce Coupons are stored in Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979138/how-woocommerce-coupons-are-stored-in-database)

It is working correct and loads everything of the coupons in the database.
Instead of a SELECT query I want to DELETE all of this.

How do I need to modify the code?

```
SELECT p.`ID`, 
       p.`post_title`   AS coupon_code, 
       p.`post_excerpt` AS coupon_description, 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,          -- Discount type 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,          -- Coupon amount 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'free_shipping'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,          -- Allow free shipping 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'expiry_date'        AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS expiry_date,                -- Coupon expiry date 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'minimum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS minimum_amount,         -- Minimum spend 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'maximum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS maximum_amount,         -- Maximum spend 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'individual_use'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS individual_use,         -- Individual use only 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_sale_items' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_sale_items,         -- Exclude sale items 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_ids'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,                -- Products 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_ids'AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_ids,        -- Exclude products 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,             -- Product categories 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_categories,-- Exclude Product categories 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,         -- Email restrictions 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,                -- Usage limit per coupon 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit_per_user'   AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit_per_user,   -- Usage limit per user 
       Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_count'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged                   -- Usage count 
FROM   `wp_posts` AS p 
       INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` 
WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'shop_coupon' 
       AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' 
GROUP  BY p.`ID` 
ORDER  BY p.`ID` ASC;
```

**FIXED to delete coupons from database with it's postmeta by running 2 queries:**

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_coupon';
```

```
DELETE FROM
  `wp_postmeta`
WHERE
  (
    meta_key = 'discount_type'
    OR meta_key = 'coupon_amount'
    OR meta_key = 'individual_use'
    OR meta_key = 'product_ids'
    OR meta_key = 'exclude_product_ids'
    OR meta_key = 'usage_limit'
    OR meta_key = 'limit_usage_to_x_items'
    OR meta_key = 'expiry_date'
    OR meta_key = 'free_shipping'
    OR meta_key = 'exclude_sale_items'
    OR meta_key = 'product_categories'
    OR meta_key = 'exclude_product_categories'
    OR meta_key = 'minimum_amount'
    OR meta_key = 'maximum_amount'
    OR meta_key = 'customer_email'
    OR meta_key = 'usage_limit_per_user'
  );
```

Comment: Please put YOUR code and attempts here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with most solutions:

- All direct database manipulation is dangerous, especially without backups.
- Just deleting records by `meta_key` is **dangerous**: some posts other than coupons may for example own `'product_ids'` meta data.
- Deleting specific meta keys may leave additional meta data available in different versions or by plugins behind.
- Queries need to be adjusted if the configured table prefix is not `wp_`.

Still, in many cases running such a query does make sense. A query which deletes the coupons and *exactly* determines all their associated meta data does use a join based on `wp_posts.ID`:

```sql
DELETE p, m
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
```

A somewhat less intrusive and dangerous way to do it, is to move everything into trash:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'trash' WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon'
```

... and empty the trash from within the WordPress backend. This gives plugins a chance to invoke filters and hooks and is a great solution for many `post_type`s. I would suggest to use that for more complex types should as orders with associated items, comments and more. Both queries can be limited to only affect published posts:

```sql
DELETE p, m
    FROM wp_posts p
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'trash'
    WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
```

Comment: This is the best solution, elegant and safe. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_coupon' ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

If the select statement above returns all the rows you would like to delete, then you just need to replace the select with delete and remove the order by as it isn't needed. Like so:

```sql
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'shop_coupon'
```

Comment: No only if I use all the Max rows in the query it shows everything i would like to delete. How do I need to modify the code then? (see code in my question now)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to delete from `wp_posts`, you just need to get the list of `IDs` to delete:

```sql
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `ID` IN (
  SELECT p.`ID`
  FROM   `wp_posts` AS p 
         INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` 
  WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'shop_coupon' 
         AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' 
)
;
```

You're not referencing any of the columns in your `SELECT` list, so you don't need to include them in your sub-query.  You can also remove the `GROUP BY` since you just want a list of the `IDs`.

You can probably re-write the `DELETE` a little cleaner using `EXISTS` or a join instead of `IN`, but either way will give you the same result.

Comment: When using this query with SELECT * FROM instead of DELETE FROM it gives an error.

Comment: Assuming `ID` is the `PK` of your table, the query above will `DELETE` the same rows that your `SELECT` query would return.  Is that not what you are looking for?  What is the exact error you're getting?  And what result are you expecting?

Comment: If I copy paste your query exactly. It doesn't work so I wanted look what results would be in the query before deleting them but doesn't work either. I have 30000 coupons in WooCommerce I want to delete from the database including all it's postmeta so I can import new codes

Comment: #1064 - There is something wrong in the used syntax at 'FROM `wp_posts` AS p INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm' on rule 4

Comment: Oops, sorry.  There is a misplaced comma `(,)` after `p.ID`.  Just take that out and it should work.  I updated the query above.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN makes slightly more sense (it removes coupons for which meta data is missing, too)