# Can I extract out all the coupons from a WooCommerce store which does not belong to me?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all coupons that can be applied during Checkout in a website, just for educational purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How WooCommerce Coupons are stored in Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979138/how-woocommerce-coupons-are-stored-in-database)

Comment: @jiali I don't think it will work as I don't own the store.