# How to unify fields?

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, group-by

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid,
(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'product_ids'  AND  wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS 'product_ids',
(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS 'coupon_amount',
(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND  wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS 'discount_type',
(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'free_shipping'      AND  wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS 'free_shipping',
(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date'        AND  wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS 'expiry_date'   
FROM wp_posts 
RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('discount_type','coupon_amount', 'product_ids')
```

This way I can get the name of a coupon, its amount, and its discount type, but the query shows me as follows:

[[image]]

How can I make everything appear in 1 single row? Like this:

[[image]]

And the important thing, I also need to filter it by product ID, in the photo you can see that the ID is 725

Answer (score 0):

For this sample data you can do it with aggregation:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'product_ids'  AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'coupon_amount' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'free_shipping' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS expiry_date   
FROM wp_posts RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('discount_type','coupon_amount', 'product_ids')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid
```

Also with this condition:

```
wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
```

since it is applied in the `WHERE` clause, you are actually doing an `INNER` join instead of a `RIGHT` join.
If this isn't what you want move it to the `ON` clause:

```
FROM wp_posts RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon' 
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('discount_type','coupon_amount', 'product_ids')
```

Also, if you actually want an `INNER` join, then this condition:

```
AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id`
```

inside the `CASE` expressions, is not needed, because it is `true`, since it is applied in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much friend !!
And how do I tell the meta_key to identify if the value is 'product_ids' and the meta_value to identify if the value is 725 (this would be the product_id).

in this way to be able to identify the coupons for each product

Comment: The condition for `'product_ids'` is included in the list of the operator IN, if this is what you are asking. Also, the MAX() function, when applied to values like null, null, 725 will return 725.

Comment: I would like to show only the coupons created for each product, example:
for product 725 = 2 coupons
for product 687 = 1 coupon

Comment: This is what you get with this query: for product 725 = 2 coupons, for product 687 = 1 coupon, as I see in the results of your query, if all 4 columns: wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid have the same values.

Comment: Correct, but there I show all the coupons, but how do I only show the coupons for each product_id.

For example, if someone walks in to see product 725, I will show them only 2 coupons.
If someone goes to see product 687, they will only see 1 coupon.
This I show with php

Comment: My answer is about the question as you posted it, meaning about removing redundant rows and show only 1 row for each combination of wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid. I don't know what a coupon is, and what a product_id is. If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.

Comment: please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769306/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-woocommerce-orders-which-use-a-particular-coupon/42771538#42771538